# Why InitializingBean's method wont be called in a normal Java File

Tags: java, spring

Let's say in my java class I have

```
class myClass{
  public static void main ..{
    Validator validator;
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactory = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    validator = localValidatorFactory.getValidator();
  }
```

On the last line I get nullPointerException. That is because in my localValidatorFactory, `ValidatorFactory` attribute is null and I guess that is responsible to get me the validator.

Now, my question is that if this was a dynamic webproject and I had a context file, wherein I had defined all these classes, then in that case it would work. Because in that case the `afterPropertiesSet` method is called that sets the properties, I guess.

But why is it not working in this case? And what can I do to make it work?

Is it that, I should have contextFile, that has all this thing, and in my java file, I do `ApplicationContext.getBean()` and after such steps, it will work? Does it mean that initializingBean will work only when things are done like this? In normal java code, I can not make initializingBean work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InitializingBean` and `FactoryBean`(i.e. `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`) are callback interfaces of the spring framework but your code is not using it.

`LocalValidatorFactoryBean` may define dependencies to be autowired (i.e. resolved and injected) by the container but you create the instance yourself so there is no way for Spring to be involved and process those callbacks properly.

You could make all this work propperly in "normal java code" but calling the setter of the factory bean and `afterPropertiesSet` yourself. In that case, you're basically doing what Spring does automatically for you when `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` is a Spring managed bean.

Comment: Will it work, if I do ApplicationContext.getBean(). Will the afterPropertiesSet Method be called in that case?  Thanks

Comment: Yes (you shouldn't have to worry about that)

Comment: I am sorry but I did not get 'you shouldnt have to worry about that'. What exactly does that mean? Thanks

Comment: As long as your object is managed by Spring, all callbacks will be processed as they should.